# Visual Studio taking a long time to search for references

Tags: c#, c++, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am running VS 2010 SP1, and using a solution with 120+ projects in it. When I search for references in a C# project, I get my results pretty quickly. However, in our sole VB.NET project (we're in the process of slowly converting it to C#) when I search for references to a function for example, it gets hung up on looking through C++ projects, and takes forever to search through them. Is there a way to speed this up or ignore the C++ projects when searching for references? There are only two native C++ projects and they aren't very large (we have no C++/CLI projects), and since I never work with the C++ projects I'd like to be able to ignore them when searching for references, or at least speed up the process in some way.

In addition, this is also happening when I'm searching for references on a private member. Why does this happen and can I also make it so that I don't look for external references on my private VB.NET members?

I can provide additional clarification if necessary. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I find pretty often that any search feature in VS takes much more time (and sometimes is broken) when I'm currently debugging. Are you debugging?

Comment: No, although it does take forever when debugging. This issue persists when I'm just editing code.

Comment: Get trial version of jetBrains Resharper. Use it and see if it speeds up your project.

Comment: Would you consider loading the VB.NET project into a solution that doesn't include all those projects you don't care to search?

Comment: If he separates projects out of solution, he will not be able to use method call search.